# How to centre a MenuBar

Tags: html, css

Hi I'd like to center my menu bar and haven't had any luck, below is the css coding

```
#menubar
width:940px;
height:50px;
float:left;
text-align:center;
```

Comment: Please share html also.

Comment: Try this: http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_align_container

Comment: Remove the float and add `margin: 0 auto`

Answer (score 1):

You tried using `text-align: center;` which aligns content of your element in the center.

If you want to center your element with respect to its container (which may be the `body` of your page or another element), you can do this:

```
#menubar {
    width: 940px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}
```

by setting left and right margins to `auto` you are instructing the browser to give an equal value, thus centering it.

Comment: you destruct the menu since he uses float:left :D

Answer (score 0):

Please update your css by this

```
     #menubar {
             width: 940px;
             height: 50px;
             text-align:center;
             margin: 0 auto;
     }


<div id="menubar"></div>
```